# Where to find database for breast cancer phenotype?

Tags: database, cancer

Where can I find databases for breast cancer mutations (SNPs & indels) phenotype, with chromosome, position, ref, alt, gene, clinical significance.

So far, I have only found the Clinvar database.

I need to extract data for breast cancer, in order to train a machine learning model that will be able to predict the pathogenicity of variants (benign, pathogenic etc).

So I did the extraction of data from clinvar vcf file (chromosome, ref, alt, clinical significance), but the clinvar data for breast cancer is very small.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this (a product of the BRCA Challenge project):

> https://brcaexchange.org/

[image]

Comment: yes it helps thank you

Comment: in addition,  Maryem,  • the following may need to note • `To gain biological insights, we frequently associate mutational signatures with factors such as driver mutations, germ line variation, epigenetic modifications, and environmental or therapeutic exposures. However, these remain associations until causation is proven.`

Comment: [link] (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353501050_Mutational_signatures_emerging_concepts_caveats_and_clinical_applications)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18JPIjuPZPM2hnj5O18T4HeQnNil3fU9u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ARmO9q9JooamZ_WgNMRuwIjvxKqtMaj5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://ugc.futurelearn.com/uploads/files/ca/71/ca712acd-e23a-4b3b-b228-45ee17ba1d9e/1_10_HGVS_nomenclature_KTB_AF_CL_KTB_AF2_JD_AF3_KTB_FINAL.pdf